# How to get the first occurrence of a group by with all the columns, using postgresSql or jpa?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

i have this table "test"

```
id, limite, unidade, algo
1   1       1        aegeg
2   1       1        srhrh
3   2       1        gesrsrhbg
4   2       1        egWRG
5   2       2        ftgjd\h
```

id is unique, but algo is not unique.

I want in the output, all the columns.

I want to group by limite and unidade.

I want the following output, which I can produce with:

```
select limite, unidade 
from test 
group by limite, unidade

limite, unidade
1       1
2       1
2       2
```

Plus the columns, id and algo, from the first occurrence of the group which would be

```
id, limite, unidade, algo
1   1       1        aegeg
3   2       1        gesrsrhbg
5   2       2        ftgjd\h
```

But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: There are loads of answers for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+greatest-n-per-group

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id, a.limite, a.unidade, t.algo
from (
    select 
       min(id) as id,
       limite,
       unidade
    from test
    group by 
       limite,
       unidade
) a
   left join test t on t.id = a.id
```

Comment: Oh, thanks Shpioni, it worked, i tried to upvote your answer but i have no reputation to do it. Now i will try to reproduce it on jpa.